# Max Login Attempts for Docker MySQL and PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, docker-compose

I have a functioning MySQL database and PHPMyAdmin client that connects to it. Both live in docker containers created via Docker-Compose.yml. I would like to implement a max number of logins and then lock the user out either permanently, or ideal for a set amount of time. I am having difficulty finding if there some sort of easy way to set this up with environment variables in the docker-compose or something like that? If so can someone please help me out, if not any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything in Docker that would accomplish what you're asking.

Rather than reinventing the wheel, as the saying goes, you might use some script or program specifically meant to do this. As far as I know, the de facto standard for this is [Fail2ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). https://serverfault.com/questions/435016/custom-fail2ban-filter-for-phpmyadmin-bruteforce-attempts seems to have more information about doing that; abstracting the configuration details to a Docker configuration is probably relatively straightforward.